# Sass @function: define a list of accepted values

Tags: css, sass

Is possible to list the values accepted by one argument? For example: I want to make that limit `$unit` argumnent for the number 1,2,4,8.

```
@function spacing($unit) {
  @return $base-unit * $unit;
}
```

Comment: try if condition

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
@function spacing($unit) {
  @if $unit != 1 and $unit != 2 and $unit != 4 and $unit != 8 {
    @error "Unit value should be 1, 2, 4 or 8";
  }

  @return $base-unit * $unit;
}
```